# How to add list file of SD card to set meta data set change

Tags: android, google-drive-api

How to add list of SD card file to meta data set change on Google Drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to [upload the files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads) from the SD Card to Drive. After that, you can retrieve the list of files from Drive.

Setting the metadata to the `DriveFile` can be done by using [`MetadataChangeSet`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/MetadataChangeSet.html). After setting the appropriate values, you should call [`DriveResource.updateMetadata`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveResource.html#updateMetadata(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient, com.google.android.gms.drive.MetadataChangeSet)). More information about it can be found on [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/metadata)